# Reactjs: page refreshing upon `onClick` handle of Button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following block inside my `render()` (which is a Bootstrap Button: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#buttons-options):

```
<Button type="simpleQuery" onClick={this.handleEntailmentRequest.bind(this)}>
   Query
</Button>
```

and the following function:

```
handleEntailmentRequest() {
    console.log("handle request ");
}
```

Whenever I click on the button I can see that the "handle request" question appears in the console log, but suddenly disappears. My understanding is that something is causing the page to refresh. Any opinons where I am going wrong?

Comment: The issue I had was trying to be clever and making the entire list item clickable.  So when I console logged the data I was fetching, it rendered for every single list item.  The only solution was to add a button to handle the click event and now it works fine.  Either that or make the entire list item a button hehe.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The default button action is to submit the form.

If you don't need that - you need to prevent that:

```
handleEntailmentRequest(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("handle request ");
}
```

References:

- [MDN - `Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: In Reactjs (tsx file), I made it work as folloiwing, **handleEntailmentRequest(e:Event) { .... }**

Answer (score 21):

You can prevent the default behavior as suggested by zerkms or

Just add type="button" in button tag.

Eg:  this.showSomething('all')}>All

Answer (score 20):

The full solution for the issue of the page reloading will be:

```
<Button type="simpleQuery" onClick={(e) => {this.handleEntailmentRequest(e)}}>
   Query
</Button>


handleEntailmentRequest(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do something...

}
```

Answer (score 6):

After adding the attribute `type="button"` in React solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! That did worked!
If your react-app gets refreshed unexpectedly then, you should pass (e) as an event argument and then use `e.preventDefault()` in the function body which will prevent happen the default behavior of the onClick event.

Answer (score 1):

*You can also try this:*

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  
  function refreshPage() {
    window.location.reload(false);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={refreshPage}>Click to reload!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this helps at this point. but I added type="button" to the button I was using and my issue got solved. I don't think this would happen with other button elements. I used anchor tag and that is why I ran in to that issue. I used anchor tag in the following way and my problem went away.

```
<a type="button" onClick={}></a>
```